# How to store context managable objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, contextmanager

I have an object `foo` which has an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method.

Now I have the need to store multiple instances of `foo` in a `list` on another object `bar` and would like for `bar` to be context manageable, too.

1. How do I create and append `foo` correctly? The following seems to be fishy:

   ```
   def blub(self):
       f = foo(args)
       f.__enter__()
       self.mylist.append(f)
   ```
2. How to handle the returned objects of `foo.__enter__()`?
3. How do I implement `__exit__` in `bar` so that it delegates correctly?

---

As requested a more concrete example with `open` replacing `foo`.

```
class bar:
  def __init__(self, path):
    self.mylist = list()

  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def blub(self, path):
    f = open(path, "w")
    f.__enter__() # What to do with the object returned?
    self.mylist.append(f)

  def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    pass # How do I delegate __exit__ to all instances in mylist and handle exceptions?
```

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example?

Comment: I think what jon meant to ask is: What are `foo` and `bar` really? How are they expected to behave? That's important info for answering your question.

Comment: @Rawing `bar` is pretty similar to the example and you can thing about `foo` as a kind of `open`, where for `__exit__` a file should be produced.